# mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have created an android application,by using this function in php i am creating a
a new user in database mysql.

```
function signUp($sName, $sMobile, $sAddress, $sEmail, $sPwd)
    {
    $sql = "insert into customers (name,mobile,address,email,pwd) values ('$sName','$sMobile','$sAddress','$sEmail','$sPwd')";
    $run = $this->query($sql);
    if ($this->result <= 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $this->json('DATA');
    }
}
```

With the below function i am querying in database and returning the response in json format

```
function query($sql){
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$this->result[] = $row;
}
return $this;
}
```

but the response i am getting has an error i tried surpessing the warnings by using

```
@mysql_fetch_assoc($query)
```

It gave a proper response in browser but android gets null as response

Error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at

Help required New to PHP. Thanks in advance

Comment: don't suppress the error if you know there is. you have to solve it. by the way, stop using `mysql_query()` , use MySQLi or PDO instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get result by

```
Insert Query
```

but you can get id of current inserted user by

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

and then you can use "Select Query" against that id.

Answer (score 1):

**INSERT QUERY does not return RESULT SET**

Only **SELECT** query returns result set

Comment: Not Only SELECT return result set.
At least these will return result set too: SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN

Comment: So what should i do to return a result in json for android?.

Comment: Yep - an option would be to do a SELECT to get the latest inserted data: `SELECT name, mobile, address, email FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER id DESC LIMIT 1` (assuming your primary key is `id`). A more proper (but more complicated) way to do it is documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367018/get-updated-row

Comment: @user1208523 Return `true` when data is inserted in database and `false` when it does not insert data in database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the thing is that Your query is INSERT query and, according, to PHP Manual, in successful query it return true, not mysql object. So function "mysql_fetch_assoc($query)" cannot be ran because it requests mysql object as parameter not only TRUE.
Also, I recommend to start using MySQLi or PDO extensions, instead of mysql_* functions.

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.
>
> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a
>   SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows
>   were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
>   have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.