# Check record value after update stored proc MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

This executes a stored proc

```
EXEC dbo.Web_update
 @hHomeEmail = 'me@me.com',
 @pPassword = 'XXXXX',
 @mMemberID = '123456'
```

stored proc

```
 UPDATE Member 
 SET pass_w = @pPassword, 
 HomeEmail = @hHomeEmail
 WHERE MemberID=@mMemberID;
```

I would like to check the values of HomeEmail and pass_w after the UPDATE if NULL or not to return boolean value as a result of that call.

----------UPDATE ----------

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Web_update] Script Date: 03/21/2017 12:37:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Web_update] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @hHomeEmail nvarchar(10) = NULL,
    @MemberNo nvarchar(10) = NULL,
    @pPassword nvarchar(10) = NULL,
    @mMemberID INT

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE Member SET pass_w = @pPassword, HomeEmail = @hHomeEmail WHERE MemberID=@mMemberID;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM member WHERE MemberID=@mMemberID AND pass_w = NULL OR HomeEmail= NULL)

        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
            ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END


END
```

Now I would like to check if:

pass_w = NULL

OR

pass_w = ‘’

OR

HomeEmail = NULL

OR

HomeEmail = ‘’

if one of them is then CAST (1 AS BIT)

ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)

Comment: Why allowing null in these columns in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Updated Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367018/get-updated-row)

Comment: Why allowing null both HomeEmail and pass_w were added later to the member table. Now members can login online but have to update HomeEmail and pass_w before they can continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an output parameter to your stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Web_update
 (
     @hHomeEmail = varchar(10),
     @pPassword = varchar(10),
     @mMemberID = varchar(10)
     @@pIsNull bit OUTPUT
 )
 AS
 UPDATE Member 
 SET pass_w = @pPassword, 
 HomeEmail = @hHomeEmail
 WHERE MemberID=@mMemberID;

 SELECT @pIsNull = CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                                          SELECT 1 
                                          FROM Member 
                                          WHERE MemberID=@mMemberID 
                                          AND pass_w IS NULL 
                                          AND HomeEmail IS NULL) THEN 1 
                             ELSE 0 END As Bit)
```